# Media Queries for landscape

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a question regarding media queries css at lansdscape position.

I do struggle to make fully responsible project when it comes to very small heights, as mobile : 375px, 320px etc., everything drops at this point.

Is it correct to include all Iphone media queries like this?

```
   @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 375px) 
   and (max-device-width: 812px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
   and (orientation: landscape),
   screen 
   and (min-device-width: 414px) 
   and (max-device-width: 736px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
   and (orientation: landscape),
   screen 
   and (min-device-width: 375px) 
   and (max-device-width: 667px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape),
   screen 
   and (min-device-width: 320px) 
   and (max-device-width: 568px)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape),
   screen 
   and (min-device-width: 320px) 
   and (max-device-width: 480px)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do apologise. It seems I finally find the media query that would work for all landscape positions for mobile.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 280px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape){}
```